# Date Filter is not covering correct time range

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I have two fields ("Start date","End date") both being of type Date.

And I also have two scenarios which I'm trying to cover up - without success:

**A:** *"Start Date"* is not defined, but *"End Date"* is e. g. Start Date=**0D**,End Date=**31.12.2020**. That now means that everything between 0D till 31.12.2020 should be seen as overlapping.

The same goes with *"Start Date"* being defined and *"End Date"* not being defined e. g. Start Date=**02.02.2020**, End Date=**''**. That would be seen as 02.02.2020..∞

To visualize it, I have added a screenshot.

[image: overlapping]

> **Note:** *"Start Date"* = *"Gültig von"* and *"End Date"* = *"Gültig bis"* ).

That scenario would be overlapping, since 02.02.2020 goes till "infinity" e. g. the first row with *"End Date"* is in the range of the second row.

**B:** In this scenario the ranges are not in their way (not overlapping) e. g.  Start Date=**0D**,End Date=**31.01.2020** for the first row and Start Date=**02.02.2020**,End Date=**''** for the second row.

Again a visualisation:

[image: not overlapping]

Here we see that both rows have their own ranges (not overlapping) since the first row ends two days before the next range on the second row start.

My approach that doesn't work:

```
local procedure ValidateRandomRec()
var
    _random: Record Random;
begin
    if (Rec."Gueltig bis" = 0D) and (Rec."Gueltig von" <> 0D) then begin
        if _random.FindSet() then
            _random.SetFilter("Gueltig von", '=''''|%1..', Rec."Gueltig von")
        else begin
            _random.SetFilter("Gueltig bis", '');
            _random.SetFilter("Gueltig von", '%1..', Rec."Gueltig von");
        end;
    end;
end;

if (_random.FindSet()) and (_random.Count >= 1) then begin
       if GuiAllowed then
           Message('Date overlapping');
end;
```

Gets called im my page like this:

```
trigger OnInsert()
begin
    ValidateRandomRec();
end;

trigger OnModify()
begin
    ValidateRandomRec();
end;

trigger OnRename()
begin
    ValidateRandomRec();
end;
```

This turned out longer than expected. At least it is reproducible :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need something like this. I did it without compiler, maybe some adjustment is missing.

Try this

```
local procedure ValidateRandomRec()
var
    _random: Record Random;
    _totalReg: Integer;
begin
    _random.Reset();
    _totalReg := 0;
   
    //Scenario A
    if (Rec."Gueltig von" <> 0D) and (Rec."Gueltig bis" = 0D) then begin
        _random.SetFilter("Gueltig von", '%1..', Rec."Gueltig von");
        _random.SetRange("Gueltig bis", 0D);
        _totalReg := _random.Count;
        if(_totalReg = 1)then begin
            _random.Reset();
            _random.SetRange("Gueltig von", 0D);
            _random.SetFilter("Gueltig bis", '%1..', Rec."Gueltig von");
            _totalReg += _random.Count;     

            _random.Reset();
            _random.SetFilter("Gueltig von", '..%1', Rec."Gueltig von");
            _random.SetRange("Gueltig bis", 0D);
            _totalReg += _random.Count;
        end;
    end;

    Scenario B
    if (Rec."Gueltig von" = 0D) and (Rec."Gueltig bis" <> 0D) then begin
        _random.SetRange("Gueltig von", 0D); 
        _random.SetFilter("Gueltig bis", '..%1', Rec."Gueltig bis");
        _totalReg := _random.Count;
    end;           

    if (_totalReg > 1) then //More than one record in table with this filters
       if GuiAllowed then
           Message('Date overlapping');
    
end;
```

Comment: scenario B would work that way, but not scenario A.

Comment: Update answer, comment // filters for 0D because can or can't be 0D